# Erro ao converter string para data, com dateformatter no swift

Tags: ios, swift, data

No cadastro do usuário eu tenho um input com uma máscara nesse formato "dd/MM/YY", depois de pegar o valor do input, que vem como string, eu tenho que converte-lo para data. A conversão sempre funcionou, só com a data 25/10/1992 que ela da problema e sempre retorna nil.
O código que estou usando é esse:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
if let dateString = birthDayInput.text { // 25/10/1992
   return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) // nil
}

return nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema ocorre devido a forma que *DateFormatter* converte a data. 
Ao converter strings que não tem horário definido, *DateFormatter* assume meia-noite. A timezone também é inferida pelas configurações do dispositivo (no seu caso provavelmente GMT-2).

Acontece que em 1992, no dia 25/10 começou no Brasil o horário de verão, a meia-noite. Ou seja, o relógio saltou de 24/10 23:59:59 para 25/10 01:00:00.
Uma vez que não existiu 25/10 00:00:00, o *DateFormatter* considera a data inválida. Como você deve estar imaginando, o mesmo ocorre para qualquer outra data na qual o horário de verão começou às 00:00.

Para saber as datas de início do horário de verão você pode verificar esse [artigo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_per%C3%ADodos_em_que_vigorou_o_hor%C3%A1rio_de_ver%C3%A3o_no_Brasil).

Isto pode ser resolvido usando a propriedade *isLenient*, que faz o *DateFormatter* usar heurísticas para inferir a data a ser convertida.

```
dateFormatter.isLenient = true
```

Comment: Em vez de usar `isLenient = true` basta você configurar o calendário do DateFormatter `dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`. Outra coisa importante quando se esta parsing datas com formato fixo é usar o `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`